# Converting string (MM-DD) into datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I want to make a time-series analysis with python, but i can't convert the data into datetime because the data is still in string (MM-DD).

Period
Jan-10
Feb-10
Mar-10
Apr-10
etc

Is there any other way to convert this kind of data into datetime object?

Comment: Please provide minimal example test case.

Comment: @Muhammad What have you already done? What have you tried? Show us your code and effort. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Muhammad You can just write our own function to convert the date. It won't be time-consuming. I don't know the already written function to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use the `datetime` module. Pandas can convert strings to date when reading the data from the csv file or you can use the `to_datetime` method after the data is loaded.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

If you are using a non-standard format, then you will get better results if you specify a format string. Here, it looks like the format string is '%b-%y', which is the abbreviated month name and the two-digit year without the century.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b-%y')
```

Comment: the OP specified that the input is month-day, so the format should be `'%b-%d'`

Comment: ... and there will be need to use correct year e.g. `df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=2021))`